# How to set a linux folder as "temporary" that deletes all its content after shutdown

Tags: linux, kali-linux

i have some folders in my Linux system and i want to mark them down as "temporary" so that each time i shutdown or restart the system, it automatically delete all the content inside.

Comment: By design, Kali is not to be installed AFAIK, so everything you do with the USB or live-cd is temporary in RAM

Comment: @Gilles [Kali can be installed](https://www.kali.org/docs/installation/).

Comment: What size are we talking about, roughly? On systemd-using systems, `/run/user/(your uid)/` is a RAM disk, so it's temporary by design, but in my experience, it seems to be limited to less than 1G with 16G RAM. Still, might be good enough for the occasional logfile analysis or downloaded file?